# Unable to click on submit url in facebook instant article

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles

I have added <meta property in header.php in wordpress and enter page id in facebook instant article plugin
but still I am unable to click on submit URL

please look the below picture

[facebook instant article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTopU.png)

Comment: Did you refresh Facebook’s cache of the OG meta data after you made changes to those, by sending the URL through the debug tool?

Comment: how to do these thing

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/